# PuTTY send and receive files over serial port

Tags: putty

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to send and receive files over serial port using PuTTY. I know how to connect to a serial port using PuTTY but I do not know how to transfer files. How can I achieve both transfer and receive? I need something similar what TeraTerm does, it has Send File, and Logging properties.

Comment: Why PuTTY?  Minicom can also do what you ask.

Comment: Here's an answer that might help, even though this question's about a year old. The answer below is for Windows, but may work for Ubuntu, YMMV. This isn't my work, I'm just copy & pasting the answer so the OP might use this. [This SO question has an answer that uses plink.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826002/is-it-possible-to-send-the-content-of-text-file-over-putty-over-a-serial-port)